# Html css ul list connect break

Tags: html, list, css

[image: actual result]

The problem is that it should be displayed like this

```
                 1
  2                              3
4   5                          6   7
```

But it break the line. what should i do? i tried:

```
overflow-x:scroll/hidden;
width:auto/100%;
display:inline/inline-block;
```

in all combinations and it didn't work on [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4x692pn2/)

The idea is that it should be an horizontal scrollbar. Also resize the result window to view that the connector is breaking.

### HTML

```
<div id="tree" class="tree">
  <ul id="1">
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="you">#1</a>
        <ul id="2">
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="woman">#2</a>
            <ul id="3">
              <li>
                <a href="#" class="woman">#4</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#" class="man">#5</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="man">#3</a>
            <ul id="3">
              <li>
                <a href="#">#6</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">#7</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

### CSS

```
* { 
  margin: 0; 
  padding: 0;
}

.tree ul {
  padding-top: 20px; 
  position: relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.tree li {
  float: left; 
  text-align: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px 5px 0 5px;

  -transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

.tree li::before, 
.tree li::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute; top: 0; right: 50%;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 50%; height: 20px;
}

.tree li::after {
  right: auto; left: 50%;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.tree li:only-child::after, 
.tree li:only-child::before {
  display: none;
}

.tree li:only-child{ 
   padding-top: 0;
 }

.tree li:first-child::before, 
.tree li:last-child::after {
    border: 0 none;
}

.tree li:last-child::before {
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
}
.tree li:first-child::after {
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
}

.tree ul ul::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute; top: 0; left: 50%;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 0; height: 20px;
}
```

Comment: So... there is no HTML so no one can help you.

Comment: Please, show us the HTML markup.

Comment: done, html markup added

Comment: I have also added the css

Comment: Hmm.. add "position:absolute;min-width:1000px" to your div#tree ? Now if the width is dynamic - that's a pickle, but you can probably calculate the appropriate width, with JS.

Comment: *"Urgent"* is probably a bad idea in the title. I can't image the community welcoming the question....

Comment: @John There is no need to comment every single time a change is made

Comment: @RaduAndrei thanks for the answer, that's the solution: min-width and position absolute. Thanks a lot! Cheers. PS: thanks JGallardo for the edit

Answer (score 1):

The answer to the questions is given by RaduAndrei in the comments:

> Hmm.. add "position:absolute;min-width:1000px" to your div#tree ? Now if the width is dynamic - that's a pickle, but you can probably calculate the appropriate width, with JS.

### CSS

```
.tree { 
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 1000px
}
```